# Goryo's Vengeance and Veil of Secrecy

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I cast [Goryo's Vengeance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoryo%27s%5d%2b%5bVengeance%5d) and use [Veil of Secrecy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVeil%20of%20Secrecy%5d)'s arcane ability, to target the creature I returned with Goryo's Vengeance?

If this is possible, at what point has my opponent priority or what can he counter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No, you can not

### From the Comprehensive Rules (Ixalan (September 29, 2017))

Splice is a static ability that functions while a card is in your hand.
“Splice onto [subtype] [cost]” means “You may reveal this card from your hand as you cast a [subtype] spell. If you do, copy this card’s text box onto that spell and pay [cost] **as an additional cost to cast that spell.**” Paying a card’s splice cost follows the rules for paying additional costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2c

---

Seeing as the card is still in the graveyard, it's not a legal target for the Veil, and all spells you cast needs all its costs paid and legal targets (If it does indeed target anything.) before you can cast it.

[source](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Splice)